# Confusing Subversion Status !M

Tags: svn

How can a versioned item be "missing or incomplete" but also "modified"? This is a status on the "root" of a checked out repo:

```
!M    .
```

Trying to figure out how it could be modified and missing (there was no modified properties on the directory or anything). How would I fix this status? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the file is modified and incomplete/corrupted. From `SVN help status`:

```
'!' item is missing (removed by non-svn command) or incomplete
```